# Update value from Database. React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to update some values from the db (couchdb/pouchdb).

I have this  structure:
Authentication page 
    StartingConsumer (in which I Check if an user Is logged or not)
If the user is logged, he is redirect to HomepageUtente.

In HomepageUser I have FirstName and LastName variable and also I have a text “Modifica Profilo” to change some values in pouchdb.

Now the problem is that If I change the values through “Modifica Profilo” the values in HomepageUser (FirstName and LastName don’t change).

I have commented the code that I used before.

With the new code I have the problem that nothing change so the values “FirstName” and “LastName” don’t change.

Where is the error in your opinion? Thank you.

**StartingConsumer.js**

```
class StartingConsumer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Utente.getUtenteLoggato()
      .then(dataUtenteLoggato => {
        if (dataUtenteLoggato !== null) {
          global.utente = new Utente(JSON.parse(dataUtenteLoggato));
          //Actions.homepageutente()({ type: "reset" });
          Actions.homepageutente({ utente: global.utente });

        } else {
          Actions.loginconsumer();
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  }
```

**HomePageUtente**

```
class HomepageUtente extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        const utentelogged = this.props.utente;
        console.log("Utente Logged" + utentelogged)
        //const FirstName = global.utente.data.Person.FirstName;
        const FirstName = utentelogged.data.Person.FirstName;
        //const LastName = global.utente.data.Person.LastName;
        const LastName = utentelogged.data.Person.LastName;
        //const Username = global.utente.data.Person.FiscalCode;
        const Username = utentelogged.data.Person.FiscalCode;

        //const Roles = global.utente.data.Person.Roles
        const Roles = utentelogged.data.Roles

        return (

            <View style={style.container}>
                <View style={style.page}>
                    <Icon name="user-circle" color="#64c7c0" size={70} onPress={() => Actions.visualizzaprofilo({ cf: Username } )} />
                    <Text
                        style={{ paddingBottom: 15, textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 15, color: '#64c7c0', fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                        onPress={() => Actions.visualizzaprofilo({ cf: Username } )} >Visualizza il Profilo
                    </Text>

                    <Text
                        style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, }}>{"Benvenuto"}
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                        style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, color: '#64c7c0', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                        {FirstName} {LastName}
                    </Text>
    <Text
                        style={{ color: '#64c7c0', paddingTop: 20 }}
                        onPress={() => Actions.modificaprofilo({ cf: Username })} >MODIFICA PROFILO</Text>}
```

**ModificaProfilo.js**

```
export default class ModificaProfilo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    /*  firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      dateOfBirth: "",
      address: "",
      city: "",
      country: "",
      email: "",
      height: "",
      weight: "",
      shoesModel: ""*/
    };
  }

  findUtente(cf) {
    let params = {};
    console.log(cf)
    params = {
      "Person.FiscalCode": cf
    };

    global.utente.db
      .localdb()
      .find({
        selector: params
      })
      .then(response => {
        let utente = response.docs[0];
          utente.Person.FirstName = this.state.FirstName;
          utente.Person.LastName = this.state.LastName;
          utente.Person.City = this.state.City;
          utente.Person.Address = this.state.Address;

console.log("utente" + utente)
        return global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente);
```

Comment: Where is the code that updates the values? or the Text “Modifica Profilo”

Comment: @Auticcat I have edit the post

Comment: @Auticcat I call Modifica Profilo at the end of HomePageUtente

Comment: So it's a child component you call inside of homePageUtente?

Comment: @Auticcat Yes it's a sort of child component that I call inside HomePageUtente to modify some data (like FirstName, Surname and other data that I don't insert during the signup)

Comment: So you are able to pass functions as props to it? I don't see a render function inside the ModificaProfilo component

Comment: @Auticcat I think that the problem is in HomePageUtente. In particular how I initialize the variable like `const FirstName = utentelogged.data.Person.FirstName`, because if I use `utentelogged.data....` , I see the old value (not the modify one), if I delete `data`, there is an error about this variable FirstName, maybe about I pass the value from StartingConsumer

Comment: The problem is that ModificaProfilo is not updating the value globally, updating only in that instance, you either need to transform it into a function inside HomePageUtente or using `redux `

Comment: @Auticcat ok, so If I want to transform it directly into a function inside HomePageUtente How can I do??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195674/discussion-between-auticcat-and-jack23).